# String split data if condition from another column was met

Tags: python, string, dataframe, split, series

I have data formed like this:

```
| Company           | Value    |
| ------————————————| -------- |
| ABC Inc/BCD Corp. | 1        |
| CDE Inc./ABG Corp | 11       |
| AGB Inc/GHU Corp. | 5        |
```

And I want to split the Companies thru a ‘/‘ delimiter only if the Value is > 1.

Thus, the result should look like this:

```
| Company           | Value    |
| ------————————————| -------- |
| ABC Inc/BCD Corp. | 1        |
| CDE Inc.          | 11       |
| ABG Corp          | 11       |
| AGB Inc           | 5        |
| GHU Corp.         | 5        |
```

I already have a code for it, but it applies to all companies, not to companies with a value of more than 1.

Comment: If you have the code, Please share the minimum reproducible code so that we can check what is the cause of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on `Company` column where `Value` > 1 and then use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).

```
m = df['Value'] > 1
df.loc[m, 'Company'] = df.loc[m, 'Company'].str.split('/')
df = df.explode('Company')
print(df)




             Company  Value
0  ABC Inc/BCD Corp.      1
1           CDE Inc.     11
1           ABG Corp     11
2            AGB Inc      5
2          GHU Corp.      5
```